# setting both the background of html and body

Tags: css

I am looking at the following code :

```
body{
background: black;}

html{
background: green
}
```

https://codepen.io/anym1994/pen/VwbbBZZ. Supposedly, I should get an almost black screen with the margin being green. However that is not what is showing on codepen. Am I not correct about the expected behavior?

update: what is making this more confusing is, if I try the same code https://cssbattle.dev/play/1 here, my expected behavior does show up without putting any element in the body to expand its height.

Comment: Your body height may be 0px

Answer (score 3):

Yes it will work how you mentioned. but you have to add the elements to the body for you to see the black screen and the margin to be green. I added some headings for you to get an understanding. This is the html code I got. You can add it in codepen.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hi</h1>
    <h1>Hi</h1>
    <h1>Hi</h1>
    <h1>Hi</h1> <!-- Add more to get more black screen -->
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Or you can use something like this. You can set a specific area unlike the above one.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>      
  
  <head>
     <style>
        #footer {
           background: #00ff00;
           padding: 100px;
        }
     </style>
  </head>
    
  <body>
   <body style="background-color:black;">
     <div id="footer">
        <div class="footer-text">Text</div>
     </div>
  </body>   
 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

as [@januw a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68417217/setting-both-the-background-of-html-and-body/68417348#comment120914087_68417217) commented, your body height might be `0`

so you can add the height and width to be fullscreen like this :

```css
body{
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```